# Turn off IE 9 Download Manager Popup Window

Tags: internet-explorer-9, download-manager

Is there anyway to just click on a link to download my `PDF`, it opens up and I do a `Save As` from there without having to go through the Download Manager every time?

Comment: There is no way to disable the download manager in IE9. The only way to accomplish what you want is to use an alternative browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2678934 
Be aware though that "assoc .pdf" may return .pdf=AcroExch.Document.11, whereas in my case I had to add AcroPDF.PDF.1 to the reg key.